# ASP.NET MVC Custom ModelMetadataProvider and ModelValidatorProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, modelmetadata

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I have metadata based model defined in database. I have a custom object defining the metadata of the data and uses dataset for DTO.  To display this, I am planning to write a custom ModelMetadataProvider and ModelValidatorProvider.

Is this the right approach?

Any pointers on custom ModelMetadataProvider and ModelValidatorProvider?

Comment: This post http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/9/creating_custom_modelvalidatorprovider tells how to create a custom modelvalidatorprovider when they have the validation rule setup in xml file or database. I hope this will help someone visiting this thread.

Answer (score 5):

The last day or so I was trying to figure out the same.
It seems that writing a custom ModelMetadataProvider and ModelValidatorProvider is the way to go if you have metadata / validation configuration stored on database, some file or wherever.

I found [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Customizing-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Metadata-and-Validation.aspx) a great starting point.

Did you in the meantime already hacked together a solution?
HTH,

Manu.